# Managing Quasar dialogs in Vuejs 3

Tags: data-binding, vue-component, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I created a Quasar dialog component to show errors to users in the form of popups. I maintain a variable for `q-dialog` to show up (i.e., `<q-dialog v-model="show">`, where `show` is a reactive and set to `true` in `setup()`). I use this component from another component as such `<Error v-if="movieChoiceStatus.error" :textContent="movieChoiceStatus.errorText" :show="true"/>` where `movieChoiceStatus` is a reactive as well. The problem is `Error` component shows up only once. It won't pop after initial one. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a prop for your dialog model. I can't be sure without seeing more of the code, but you might try removing the "show" prop, and just having it as a ref in the Error component set in the setup.